# rails paperclip customize upload url path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my upload.rb

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :post
      has_attached_file :upload,styles: { medium: ["500x400>",:jpg], thumb: ["100x100>",:jpg]},url: "/post_images/post_:postid/:style/:filename"

def postid
      self.post_id
end
end
```

I have a column with post_id. As `belongs_to` represents i will have more than one images for one post. But while saving files in folder instead of `post_25`. It is storing as `post_:postid`

But if i give as `:id` it is working.

How can i solve it. can anyone help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [Paperclip's interpolations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations) to achieve this functionality. First, start by defining an interpolation in an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/interpolations.rb
Paperclip.interpolates :postid do |attachment, style|
  'post_' + attachment.instance.post.id
end
```

Then, you can use the `:postid` interpolation directly in your attachment URL declaration (remember to restart your server first):

```
# app/models/upload.rb
has_attached_file :upload,styles: { medium: ["500x400>",:jpg], thumb: ["100x100>",:jpg]},url: "/post_images/:postid/:style/:filename"
```

Note that `:postid` is **not** merely the instance method you've defined in your model – Paperclip *exclusively* utilizes interpolations to define dynamic variables within URL/path declarations.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my models I have

```
Paperclip.interpolates :invoice_file_name do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.invoice_file_name
end
```

which was taken from Paperclip wiki on Github.